# Start Multiple Instances of an activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I want to create multiple instances of an activity from `BroadcastReceiver`, the activity contains a `AlertDialog`, currently I am using the following code for this purpose:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MultipleInstanceActivity.calss);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in manifest file `android:launchMode="standard"` somehow I think this  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` causing the `android:launchMode="standard"` to change to `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or something. I am not able to create multiple instances of this activity. I also tried to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`, but no use.

I have created a `PreferenceActivity`, what really puzzles me is that when this `PreferenceActivity` is open my app creates multiple dialogbox i.e multiple instances with different data on it. But when its not open, my app wont create multiple instances just to make clear, it wont open another dialog. Logcat is not giving any warnings or errors.

#### My questions:

1. How to create multiple instances of an activity from  `BroadcastReceiver`?
2. Can someone explain me whats happening in the second case, the `PreferenceActivity` one, why is it creating multiple instances?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to start multiple Activities?  Only one can be visible at a time, so I don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: Basically its a simple app that makes create a dialogbox showing the contents of a text message, now I need multiple instances because if I received a SMS and for some reason I am unable to read it, it should create another dialog showing the contents of new activity. This is happening only when `PreferenceActivity` is open.

Comment: Doest make sense. New activity will be another activity and not another instance of current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you have here, and i solved it by Using both FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this works for you too.